# OpenLayers - dynamic POI example does not work on my machine

Tags: dictionary, mapping, openlayers

OpenLayers has a good example which I would like to reuse:

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/dynamic-text-layer.html

But when I download it and run on my machine, it does not work.
It also does not work when I download
 OpenLayers-2.10.zip from openlayers.org site, unpack it on my machine and run this example.

When I say "does not work" I mean the map is displayed but there are no POIs/markers/popups.

I use windows XP.
It seems this example does NOT use proxy.cgi.

Could you please help me?
What I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Maxim

Answer (score 0):

The example you are trying to run is reading points from a text file(textfile.txt) that is fetched asynchronously. In order to get this work you have to run this code on a webserver. I guess you are running code directly from filesystem, i.e. doubleclick dynamic-text-layer.html file.

You could install [Visual Studio 2010 express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/) which is free. It has built in webserver so you will only have to open OpenLayers 2.10 map as a Web Site and push "Run"